# View contract details in a Django application

Tags: dapp-development, crowdsale

I'm trying to create Crowdsale using Ethereum. I've done everything from Token creation, to DAO creation, to Crowdsale creation in Ethereum Wallet. Now, I want my web app (built in Django) to be able to view details in the contract such as how many coins are left, how much is a coin in ETH, what is the goal in a Crowdsale. How will I be able to do this?

Comment: If you haven't yet, I recommend that you check out web3.py at https://github.com/pipermerriam/web3.py (I'm a contributor).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Run an Ethereum node, or find someone who will let you use theirs. (For example, [Infura](https://infura.io/) provide the use of Ethereum nodes as a service.) You can make queries against the blockchain via that node using [pyethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum). This gives you a lot of flexibility to make whatever calls you need against your contract.
2. Use a service that gives you data about the blockchain via a REST API. There are several companies offering developer APIs, notably [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/apis). This may be simpler if their API supports the features you need.

Comment: Can I use Etherscan even to call contracts from the Rinkeby testnet?

Comment: Also, I can't see a function to retrieve the remaining amount for the ICO to succeed, do I need to read all the transactions in the block and add it?

Comment: an alternative to etherscan but more focussed on reading/writing to contracts: https://cinder.cloud/ethereum-contract-api

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to decide whether to query blockchain on client side or on server side.  In the former case you will probably need to use [Web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/).  In the latter case you will need to use [Web3.py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Also, there should be some Ethereum node to connect to.  In case of client-side implementation it may be provided by your users, or you may use node from some public node provider such as [Infura](https://infura.io/).  In case of server-side implementation you will need to either run node yourself or again you may use node provided by [Infura](https://infura.io/) or some other cloud node provider.